# allowing specific UIViewController to rotate

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have an app with several dozen UIViewControllers.
The app is declared portrait only so does not rotate when screen is rotated.
I wish to allow one specific view to rotate.

tried adding the following

```
open override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
}


override internal func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    let orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape]
    return orientation
}

override internal func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true;
}
```

did not work.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Not enough information. Only the _top_ view controller in the hierarchy gets to dictate when the app is allowed to rotate; you have not described the view controller hierarchy. Moreover, if your "app is declared portrait", no view controller can _ever_ permit rotation — the app wins.

Answer (score 1):

> The app is declared portrait

That's part of your problem right there. If the app allows only portrait, what the individual view controllers say doesn't matter — the app wins.

The app's job is to declare every orientation the app will *ever* be allowed to assume. Then, individual view controllers (at the top level of the view control hierarchy, or their designated children or delegates) may declare a *subset* of those orientations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also implement the appDelegates supportedInterfaceOrientations:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
```

What I would do, is add a local variable to the AppDelegate which keeps the currently allowed orientations and return it here:

```
var allowedOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
{

        return self.allowedOrientations
}
```

When your specific screen opens, update the AppDelegate's support with the newly supported orientations.

Also, if your view is inside of a UINavigationController, you might need to inherit UINavigationController and override these methods as well, and just fetch what you have in the app delegate:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask
{
    // TODO: Set a new orientation if needed

    // Return the newly set orientation
    if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    {
        return delegate.allowedOrientations
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait 
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool
{
    return (Whatever the condition is for orientation)
}
```